# CoAPs TinyDTLS issues

Tags: security, dtls, cooja

I whish to study security protocols in IoT and how the impact the performance of constrained devices. My goal is to compare CoAP vs CoAPs (secured with DTLS) using Cooja simulator.

I found this fork of Contiki 3.0
https://github.com/rfuentess/contiki/tree/Contiki-CoAPS

In the contiki/examples/ipv6/CoAP-IDS/IPv6_HC06_TinyDTLS folder there is a CoAPs client and server example developed using such apps as TinyDTLS 0.8.2 and a modification of erbium-coap renamed er-coaps (with the DTLS preamble).

Before running the example in Cooja I configured tinydtls in the apps folder launching the command 
./configure --with-contiki --without-ecc
(I've read that there are some issues related to ecc criptography and for the moment I'm using the PSK_WITH_AES_128_CCM mode)

After that I deployed 3 wismote nodes in Cooja:

1 6LoWPAN Border router flashed with the firmware (contiki/examples/ipv6/rpl-border-router/border-router.c)

1 CoAPS client flashed with the firmware (contiki/examples/ipv6/CoAP-IDS/IPv6_HC06_TinyDTLS/coaps-client.c)

1 CoAPS server flashed with the firmware (contiki/examples/ipv6/CoAP-IDS/IPv6_HC06_TinyDTLS/coaps-server.c)

I'm facing 2 problems:

1) Why there are the several retransmit tentative (at second 10) of the the client hello to the server (see the mote output attachment below)?

2) Looking at the client code (contiki/examples/ipv6/CoAP-IDS/IPv6_HC06_TinyDTLS/coaps-client.c), the example is supposed to retrieve several CoAP resources, but it gets stuck trying to retrieve the first one (.well-known/core). It seems that the program freezes during the COAP_BLOCKING_REQUEST() and won't procede retrieving other resources. Why?

I'm attaching the motes output and PCAP file.

[Motes_output](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1tEHo3becRRdNkjqiMlvTAqbkkt5BQzOr/view?usp=sharing)

[PCAP](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1SUnQcOli970y3BtbfmQNH97TWRunQls4/view?usp=sharing)

Thanks